# How to change the curl command to python's request format

Tags: python, curl

I succeeded in verifying that my image was sent to the server via curl
However, I would like to import the Python language request module
My code looks like this
Thanks for your help

## Curl

```
curl -X POST --header 'x-user-token: [Token]' --header 'x-user-email: [Email]' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F 'note[message]=hello' -F 'note[image]=@HelloWolrd.jpg' http://[URL]
```

## Python

```
URL = "[URL]"
EMAIL = "[Email]"
TOKEN = "[Token]"
headers = {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Content-Type': 'application/json; multipart/form-data',
'x-user-token': TOKEN,
'x-user-email': EMAIL}

data = {
'message': "Hello"
}
res = requests.post(URL, files={'image': open("[file_name].jpg", "rb")}, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
import requests

headers = {
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
'x-user-token': '[Token]',
'x-user-email': '[Email]',
}

files = [
('note[message]', 'hello'),
('note[image]', open('HelloWolrd.jpg', 'rb')),
]

requests.post('http://[url]/', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: I found a better way.
I will try to solve this with the help of https://curl.trillworks.com/
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I solved this problem.
Look back at my question to solve this problem
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## P.S

I did not solve it with the answer below but eventually I did it.
If you need my help, please refer to the code below
It is better to remove unnecessary headers
Check the header of your code

## Resloved Python Code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import requests
import logging
import base64

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET)

headers = {
'x-user-token': '[Token]',
'x-user-email': '[Email]',
}

files = {
'note[image]': (open("[file_name].jpg", "rb"), 'image/jpeg')
}

data = {
'note[message]': 'Hello World !'
}

res = requests.post('http://[URL]', headers=headers, files=files, data=data)

print(res.request.headers)
print(res.headers)

f = open('temp.log', 'w')
f.write(res.text)
f.close()

if res.status_code != 200:
    print(res.status_code)
```